# defining a function using a typedef inside a define macro

Tags: c++, typedef, c-preprocessor

I have seen typedef and #define used in seperate scenarios. However, I have never come across code with one inside the other. Namely, the following

```
#define DECL_STDXL_FUNC(apiname, apitype, args)    \
  typedef XLstatus (_XL_EXPORT_API *apitype) args
```

This is later used to declare a function prototype (apparently) like this

```
DECL_STDXL_FUNC ( xlGetChannelTime,   XLGETCHANNELTIME, (
              XLportHandle        portHandle, 
              XLaccess            accessMask,
              XLuint64            *pChannelTime )
);
```

Basically, the header file is supposed to define functions that I only have the dll for. This suggests to me that I need to use _declspec(dllimport) and the correspond export of that. But the above just does not make any sense to me. Can anybody help make sense of this definition? If you need more clarification on the code, I can absolutely provide it. This is by far the most frustrating and convoluted way I've ever seen a function prototype written.

Comment: Yeah I'd pretty much fire someone for writing nonsense like this. It has no place in modern production code. There is just no need.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It looks like it might be used for the trick of including the same code twice but with a different definition of the macro  active each time: once to declare functions, and once to declare function pointer typedefs.  This trick is good in some situations: it avoids the error of having two different lists that get out of sync.

Comment: @MattMcNabb There are a lot of defines at the top of the code, and I think that is exactly what it's used for. Since the implementer doesn't know ahead of time whether I will dynamically link to the code or not, they defined it for both cases.

Comment: I'm curious about the unused `apiname` argument to the function.  Is this in fact an 'X macro'?  That is, there are actually a number of different `#define` versions of `DECL_STDXL_FUNC`, and some of those use the `apiname` argument?  For example, there might be `#define DECL_STDXL_FUNC(apiname, apitype, args) extern XLstatus apiname args` as an alternative (probably without the `extern` and maybe with extra decorations like `_XL_EXPORT_API`) so that the same code that defined the typedef could also be used to declare the actual function?

Comment: Well, at the top of the header file is this  piece of code extern apitype apiname. But, it is not directly defined in the header. I'm left to assume it's definition is somewhere in the dll.

Comment: And you are correct that DECL_STDXL_FUNC has a couple of definitions defined. Mostly for use cases involving dynamical linking vs static linking

Answer (score 2):

Run it through the preprocessor, at least mentally (this is what I'm doing):

```
#define DECL_STDXL_FUNC(apiname, apitype, args)    \
  typedef XLstatus (_XL_EXPORT_API *apitype) args
```

Interesting: the `apiname` argument to the macro is unused.

```
DECL_STDXL_FUNC ( xlGetChannelTime,   XLGETCHANNELTIME, (
              XLportHandle        portHandle, 
              XLaccess            accessMask,
              XLuint64            *pChannelTime )
);
```

When translated, this becomes:

```
typedef XLstatus (_XL_EXPORT_API *XLGETCHANNELTIME)(XLportHandle portHandle, 
              XLaccess accessMask, XLuint64 *pChannelTime);
```

That is, `XLGETCHANNELTIME` becomes a name for a specific pointer to function type.  The `_XL_EXPORT_API` is presumably related to importing from or exporting to shared library (DLL) symbol lists.  And the various `XLlowercase` names are types defined by the code.

You'll be able to define variables of this type:

```
XLGETCHANNELTIME get_channel_time = …;
```

which will presumably need to be initialized by some sort of symbol lookup function (`dlopen()` in the most common Unix-like system).